# Terraform: how to support different providers

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

I have a set of terraform codes in a directory called myproject:

```
\myproject\ec2.tf
\myproject\provider.tf
\myproject\s3.tf
      ....
```

the provider.tf shows:

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-west-1"
  profile = "default"
}
```

so, if I terraform apply in myproject folder, a set of aws resources are launched in us-west-1 under my account.

Now I want to introduce a AWS Glue resource, which is only available in a different region us-west-2. then how do I layout glue.tf file?

Currently I store it in a sub-directory under myproject and run terraform apply in that sub-directory i.e.

```
\myproject\glue\glue.tf
\myproject\glue\another_provider.tf
```

another_provider.tf is:

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-west-2"
  profile = "default"
}
```

Is it the only way to store a file launching resources in different regions? any better way?

If there is no better way, then I need to have another backend file in glue sub-folder as well, besides, some common variables in myproject directory cannot be shared.

--------- update:
I followed the link posted by Phuong Nguyen,

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-west-1"
  profile = "default"
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "oregon"
  region = "us-west-2"
  profile = "default"
}

resource "aws_glue_connection" "example" {
  provider = "aws.oregon"
   ....
}
```

But I saw:

```
Error: aws_glue_connection.example: Provider doesn't support resource:     aws_glue_connection
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use provider alias to define multiple providers, .e.g.

```
# this is default provider
provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-west-1"
  profile = "default"
}

# additional provider
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "west-2"
  region  = "us-west-2"
  profile = "default"
}
```

and then in your `glue.tf`, you can refer to alias provider as:

```
resource "aws_glue_job" "example" {
  provider = "aws.west-2"

  # ...
}
```

More details at `Multiple Provider Instances` section: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html

Comment: Hi, phuong Nguyen: Thanks I saw that link too. but when I run terraform apply, I still see  Error: aws_glue_connection.example: Provider doesn't support resource: aws_glue_connection

Comment: @user389955 sorry I'm not very familiar with AWS Glue. Is it possible that Glue connection resource is not region specific? Maybe you can try to create glue connection in one region and switch to another to see whether it's still visible

Comment: Phuong Nguyen, glue connection and all glue components have to be in us-west-2 that is why I tried to use a different providers. if I implement glue in \myproject\glue\glue.tf and use \myproject\glue\another_provider.tf, then the glue is successfully created in us-west-2, but if I put glue.tf in \myproject, together with other AWS resources, it showed that error. Note for both case, I use backend s3 to store remote state and the s3 is in us-west-1.

Comment: somehow this answer does not work for me. I got Error: aws_glue_connection.example: Provider doesn't support resource: aws_glue_connection. But I will vote the answer of Phuong Nguyen because it supposed to be resolved that way. maybe my configuration has some problem.

Comment: from the wisdom of life - even i you CAN do something, it does not mean that you should. This ^^^ approach works, but one should be really really careful to NOT mix code with configuration and unfortunately terraform providers ARE the perfect example of providing a big gun to shoot oneself in the foot .... 
P.S. I am the guy who has been refactoring already 5 months exactly this big flow in a huge terraform code base ( 70% created by Phuong Nguyen )

Comment: @YordanGeorgiev sorry, what do you mean by you are refactoring a terraform code base that's 70% created by me? I don't remember working with you before. That aside, of course there can be multiple solutions for a problem. If you have a nicer solution, please feel free to post it as an answer so that everyone can benefit from it

Comment: we have not worked together, I am working after you ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/70154370/65706

Answer (score 1):

Read my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51996318/65706) ...

Which basically means that you should keep out aws profiles and regions and what not from your terraform code as much as possible and use them as configuration as follows:

```
terraform {
    required_version = "1.0.1"

    required_providers {
      aws = {
        version = ">= 3.56.0"
        source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      }
    }

    backend "s3" {}
  }

  provider "aws" {
    region  = var.region
    profile = var.profile
  }
```

Than use `tfvars` configuration files:

```
  cat cnf/env/spe/prd/tf/03-static-website.backend-config.tfvars

  profile        = "prd-spe-rcr-web"
  region         = "eu-north-1"
  bucket         = "prd-bucket-spe"
  foobar         = "baz"
```

which you will apply during the terraform plan and apply calls as follows:

```
    terraform -chdir=$tf_code_path plan -var-file=<<line-one-^^^>>.tfvars 

    terraform -chdir=$tf_code_path plan -var-file=<<like-the-one-^^^>>.tfvars -auto-approve
```

As a rule of thumb you SHOULD separate your code and configuration always, the more mixed they are the deeper you will get into troubles ... this applies to ANY programming language / project etc. Now some wise heads will argue that terraform code is in itself configuration , but no it is not. The terraform code in your application is the declarative source code, which is used to provision your binary infrastructure used by the application source code etc. in your application ...